# Pytorch Geometric sparse adjacency matrix to edge index tensor

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, adjacency-matrix, pytorch-geometric

My data object has the `data.adj_t` parameter, giving me the sparse adjacency matrix. How can I get the `edge_index` tensor of size `[2, num_edges]` from this?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [docs](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/sparse_tensor.html):

> Since this feature is still experimental, some operations, *e.g.*, graph pooling methods, may still require you to input the `edge_index` format. You can convert `adj_t` back to `(edge_index, edge_attr)` via:
>
> ```py
> row, col, edge_attr = adj_t.t().coo()
> edge_index = torch.stack([row, col], dim=0)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`torch_geometric.utils.convert.from_scipy_sparse_matrix`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html#torch_geometric.utils.from_scipy_sparse_matrix).

```
>>> from torch_geometric.utils.convert import from_scipy_sparse_matrix
>>> edge_index = torch.tensor([
...    [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
...    [1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2],
>>> ])
>>> adj = to_scipy_sparse_matrix(edge_index)
>>> # `edge_index` and `edge_weight` are both returned
>>> from_scipy_sparse_matrix(adj)
(tensor([[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
        [1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 2]]),
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]))
```

Comment: How is this supposed to answer? I don't understand :C OP is asking for obtaining the edge_index from an adjacency matrix that has yet. Isn't this doing the exact opposite?

Comment: The `edge_index` constructed in the second input line is an example to verify against the end result. The output of `from_scipy_sparse_matrix` is a tuple, the first element of which is the answer to the OP.