# How can I get edge_attr from adjacency matrix?

Tags: graph, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I'm using torch_geometric.

The adjacency matrix is in numpy format like:

```
adj = np.array([[0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]])
```

How can I get the parameter `edge_attr` from the adjacency matrix?

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You may want to review this: It converts a scipy sparse matrix to edge indices and edge attributes, link: https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/utils/convert.html#from_scipy_sparse_matrix

Is this the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch Geometric sparse adjacency matrix to edge index tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091074/pytorch-geometric-sparse-adjacency-matrix-to-edge-index-tensor)