# how to represent an graph in a tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, igraph, pytorch-geometric

I have an graph in (igraph-python)

```
n_vertices = 3
edges = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (3, 4)]
graph = ig.Graph(n_vertices, edges)
```

How to represent the graph by a tensor like how to reach the follow point

```
Data(edge_index, x, y, train_mask)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch Geometric sparse adjacency matrix to edge index tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091074/pytorch-geometric-sparse-adjacency-matrix-to-edge-index-tensor)

Comment: I'm not sure if this  'to_scipy_sparse_matrix'  also works on igraph, I saw it more in networkx

Comment: can you give an example for it on this graph?

Comment: You can get the sparse adjacency matrix using [get_adjacency_sparse](https://igraph.readthedocs.io/en/0.10.2/api/igraph.Graph.html#get_adjacency_sparse).

Comment: it worked, thnx you two
still thinking out how and what to do for x